# Draw a line at specific position/annotate a Facetgrid in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, catplot

A have produced a boxplot with Facetgrid in seaborn the following way

```
# Import the dataset
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# Plot using FacetGrid, separated by smoke
plt.style.use('ggplot')
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="smoker", size=5, aspect=1.5)
g.map(sns.boxplot, "sex", "total_bill", palette='viridis', order=['Male', 'Female'])
plt.show()
```

I now want to draw to distinct horizontal lines in each of the plot. For instance one horizontal line (with coordinated (0,10)) **only** in the left-hand side plot and another horizontal line (with coordinates (0,30)) **only** in the right-hand side plot.

How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can get a list of axes used in the FacetGrid using `FacetGrid.axes` which returns the axes used. You can then do all of the normal matplotlib operations using these axes, such as [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html) for horizontal lines, or [`plt.text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) for putting text on the axes:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# Plot using Facegrid, separated by smoke
plt.style.use('ggplot')
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="smoker", size=5, aspect=1.5)
g.map(sns.boxplot, "sex", "total_bill", palette='viridis', order=['Male', 'Female'])

ax1, ax2 = g.axes[0]

ax1.axhline(10, ls='--')
ax2.axhline(30, ls='--')

ax1.text(0.5,25, "Some text")
ax2.text(0.5,25, "Some text")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

- It is recommended from `seaborn v0.11.0` to use figure-level functions like [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) instead of [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)
- If a different line location and annotation is required for each `axes`, then the easiest implementation is to place the locations and text into a `dict`, and flatten the `axes` returned when creating the plot.

  - Use enumerate to access each set of values from the `dict`
  - This does require knowing the order of the output plots, so the plot would need to be run, and then create the `dict` and loop to add the lines and annotations.
- Alternatively, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67522407/7758804), which extracts the row and column names for each axes with `g.row_names` and `g.col_names`. The row and column names can be used as `keys`.
- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html) and [`matplotlib.pyplot.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html) for multiple vertical or horizontal lines.

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=tips, col='smoker', row='sex', x='sex', y='total_bill', height=3)

# dict of line positions and annotations
la = {0: [5, 0.4, 0.75, 40, 'text_a'], 1: [10, 0.5, 0.75, 40, 'text_b'],
      2: [25, 0.6, 0.75, 40, 'text_c'], 3: [35, 0.7, 0.75, 40, 'text_d']}

# flatten axes into a 1-d array
axes = g.axes.flatten()

# iterate through the axes
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.axhline(la[i][0], ls='--', c='green')
    ax.axvline(la[i][1], ls='--', c='purple')
    ax.text(la[i][2], la[i][3], la[i][4], c='orange')
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Additionally, if you have a bunch of grids that you want to add one horizontal line (say at y=10) to all then you can just "map" the "plt.axhline" with your grid object:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
# Plot using Facegrid, separated by smoke
plt.style.use('ggplot')
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="smoker", size=5, aspect=1.5)
g.map(sns.boxplot, "sex", "total_bill", palette='viridis', order=['Male', 'Female'])

g.map(plt.axhline, y=10, ls='--', c='red')
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add to the top answer, if you want do the same thing with figures in cols.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_long, col="variable", size=5, aspect=1.5,col_wrap=1,sharey=False)
# df_long is a long table with 3 variables
g.map(sns.boxplot, "label", "value", palette='Set2')
g.axes[0].axhline(1, ls='--',c='r')
g.axes[1].axhline(1, ls='--',c='r')
g.axes[2].axhline(0.5, ls='--',c='r')
g.map(plt.xticks, rotation=70) 
plt.show()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q28KL.png)

Answer (score 3):

There is `axhline` and `hlines`. Simple example:

```
chart = sns.relplot(x="x", y="y", kind="line", data=df)

chart.axes[0][0].axhline(y = 10, color='black', linewidth=2, alpha=.7)
chart.axes[0][0].hlines( y = 20, color='black', linewidth=2, alpha=.7, 
                         xmin = 30, xmax = 50)
```

Seems like `hlines` allows for min-max ([documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html)) but `axhline` doesn't.