# How to 'circle' a point on an seaborn plot (to be able to refer to it in text later)?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have this `sns.relplot` that has a couple of peak points on it, I want to be able to mark/highlight these peaks to be able to refer to them, drawing a circle around them is what I had in mind, but any way to mark it will work, thanks!

[image]

Comment: You could put a vertical dashed line at each point, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891370/draw-a-horizontal-line-line-at-specific-position-annotate-a-facetgrid-in-seaborn

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;plt.plot([1100],[1.3],'o', ms=60, mec='r', mfc='none')`Try adding this