# Annotate each FacetGrid subplot using custom df (or list) using a func

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, plot-annotations

Consider the following data and FacetGrid:

```
d = {'SITE':['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A'], 'VF':[0.00, 0.78, 0.99, 1.00, 0.50],'TYPE':['typeA', 'typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC', 'typeD']} 
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 


with sns.axes_style("white"):
    g = sns.FacetGrid(data=new_df, col='SITE', col_wrap= 3, height=7, aspect=0.25, 
                      hue='TYPE', palette=['#1E88E5', '#FFC107', '#D81B60'])
    g.map(sns.scatterplot, 'VF', 'TYPE', s=100)
```

[image: Example FacetGrid]

Using another `dataframe`:

```
d = {'SITE':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'N':[10, 5, 7]} 

ann_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Where the `SITE` matches the original `new_df['SITE']`, *and* is not the same dimensions as `new_df['SITE']`, but has the corresponding length of `columns` in the `FacetGrid`.

How do you `annotate` each `subplot` using a custom `func` using **not** the scatterplot `new_df`, but the `ann_df` or custom `list`, if it matches the original `new_df['SITE']` and adds the `ann_df['N']` to each subplot as shown below:

[image]

So, something along these lines or better:

```
def annotate(data, **kws):
n = data           # should be the int for each matching SITE 
ax = plt.gca()
ax.text(.1, .2, f"N = {n}", transform=ax.transAxes)

g.map_dataframe(annotate(ann_df))
```

Answer (score 1):

- It is recommended from `seaborn v0.11.0` to use figure-level functions like [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) instead of [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)
- The values used for `col=` will be plotted alphabetically by default, otherwise specify an order with `col_order=`, and then make sure `ann_df['SITE']` is sorted in the same order.
- Flatten the `seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid` returned by `sns.relplot`, iterate through the `matplotlib.axes`, and add [`.text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) to each plot by using `i` from `enumerate` with [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to index the correct value for `'N'`.
- Similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67524391/7758804), but getting data from a secondary `DataFrame` instead of a `dict`.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# DataFrame 1
d1 = {'SITE':['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A'],
      'VF':[0.00, 0.78, 0.99, 1.00, 0.50],
      'TYPE':['typeA', 'typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC', 'typeD']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

# DataFrame 2
d2 = {'SITE':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'N':[10, 5, 7]} 
ann_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d2) 

# plot
g = sns.relplot(kind='scatter', data=df, x='VF', y='TYPE', col='SITE',
                col_wrap=3, height=7, aspect=0.5, hue='TYPE', s=100)

# flatten axes into a 1-d array
axes = g.axes.flatten()

# iterate through the axes
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.text(0, 3, f"N = {ann_df.iloc[i, 1]}")
```

[image]